# How do I fix an "Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type" error?

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to write a `remove` function, so that a user can type `remove 'd' ["abc", "dc", "ad"]` and get the output `["abc", "c", "a"]`.

My code is:

```
remove :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
remove a (x:xs) = filter (not.a) (x:xs)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = [a] -> Bool
   When generalising the type(s) for `remove'
```

What does the error message mean, and how can I change the second line so it works?

Answer (score 6):

The type of `filter` is

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

so the first argument you pass to `filter` must be a function from the element-type of the list to `Bool`. In

```
remove :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
remove a (x:xs) = filter (not.a) (x:xs)
```

you say

1. `a` has type `a`, and the list has type `[[a]]`, i.e. the list-element type is `[a]`, and
2. `not . a`, the first argument to `filter`, has type `[a] -> Bool`.

Together, these imply

```
a = [a] -> Bool
```

but that is an infinite type.

You probably meant something like `` filter (not . (a `elem`)) ``, or equivalently `` filter (a `notElem`) ``, if the `filter` is meant to work on the outer list, or `map (filter (/= a))` if you want to remove an element from each of the contained lists.

Answer (score 5):

You state that the argument `a` is any type that supports equality.

But you then use it in a boolean expression: `not . a`.

The type of `not` is `:: Bool -> Bool`, so `a` must be of type `Bool`. But you already said that no, it was of type `Eq t => t`.

So that's a type error.

I think you mean to filter all elements that do not equal `a`, which would be:

```
remove a xs = filter (/= a) xs
```

However, your input is also a nested list, so you have to map the filter over the inner elements:

```
remove a xs = map (filter (/= a)) xs
```

Comment: Thank you, you explained it well.

Comment: He's actually written `not` composed with `a`, which would not give it the type `Bool` but `[a] -> Bool` (a list because it is being applied as a filter predicate on a list of lists) as the error message says.